# Difficulty in framing a query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data as

```
A   51 12.01pm
A   53 03.00pm
B   51 04.00pm
C   51 11.55am
C   51 12.00pm
C   53 12.05pm
D   53 03.00pm
D   51 04.00pm
E   53 05.00pm
E   53 05.02pm
F   51 03.21pm
F   51 09.32pm
```

and my output should be the count of data having the latest status 53 with the latest time

Output should be A and C

Comment: HI and welcome to DBA.SE, could you clarify some things. Why would the output be A and C when C only has the highest combination of status and time --> `53, 12.05pm`. Adding the table definition and the insert statements could help.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT col1, 
              FIRST_VALUE(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 
                                      ORDER BY col3 DESC) fv 
              FROM table )
SELECT col1
FROM cte
WHERE fv = 53
```

If your server is more ancient than 2012, do the same by using `ROW_NUMBER()` and adding the condition `rownumber=1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(col1 varchar(50),col2 int, col3 time)
insert into @t VALUES
('A',51 ,'12:01 pm')
,('A',53 ,'03:00 pm')
,('B',51 ,'04:00 pm')
,('C',51 ,'11:55 am')
,('C',51 ,'12:00 pm')
,('C',53 ,'12:05 pm')
,('D',53 ,'03:00 pm')
,('D',51 ,'04:00 pm')
,('E',53 ,'05:00 pm')
,('E',53 ,'05:02 pm')
,('F',51 ,'03:21 pm')
,('F',51 ,'09:32 pm')

declare @dt datetime=cast(getdate() as date)

declare @lateststatus int=53

;with CTE as
(

select *
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by col1 order by @dt+cast(col3 as datetime) desc)rn
from @t
--where col2=@lateststatus
)

select * from cte where rn=1
```

In my script main trick is `concatenating Date with time`.

It is not clear what do you mean by `latest status 53` ?

Status may change,so it can't be hard coded.

If B latest status is 51 then it should appear in resultset or not.

So depending upon your requirement you can fix this minor thing.